# issue with CURLOPT_URL format in PERL

Tags: perl, curl, cpan

i'm trying to implement some REST API functionality in PERL using [`WWW::Curl::Easy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aCurl#WWW%3a%3aCurl%3a%3aEasy).

I suffer on curl error Code 3: "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL No URL set!
While debugging this issue it seems that there is some issue with setting the URL CURLOPT.

For Example: IMHO this testcode should return the URL http://www.example.com

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
$curl->setopt("WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLOPT_URL", 'http://www.example.com');
print $curl->getinfo("WWW::Curl::Easy::CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL");
```

but i'm getting "43" as output.

Is there a bug in my module?

- CURL WWW::Curl::Easy::Version 4.17
- perl Version v5.16.2
- System OSX 10.9

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for documentation?

The following is how the [`WWW::Curl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aCurl) docs for [`WWW::Curl::Easy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aCurl#WWW%3a%3aCurl%3a%3aEasy) demonstrate getting started:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Curl::Easy;

my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;

$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');
```